# +entityForName: nil happens intermittently

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I have a project that uses core data and this error happens intermittently. I know that the entity is there because most the time, the app opens and displays the content of the entityName. 
1. this is happening in the app delegate and not being segue'd
2. when i do [self.managedObjectModel entities], the entityName is there but app crashes
3. It is not miss-spelled.
4. It occurs the same place, the same time (app start)

```
NSManagedObjectContext *contOBJ = self.managedObjectContext;
NSEntityDescription *entity;
NSString * entityForNameString = @"MessageLists";
@try {
    entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityForNameString
                         inManagedObjectContext:contOBJ];
}
@catch (NSException* exception) {
    NSLog(@"DANGER DANGER - ERROR FOUND");
    NSLog(@"Uncaught exception: %@", exception.description);

    // ditch effort to reset manageObject BUT DOES NOT WORK...
    [self.managedObjectContext reset];
    // ditch effort to reset manageObject BUT DOES NOT WORK...

    return nil;
NSLog(@"Stack trace: %@", [exception callStackSymbols]);

    // Reset the store
}
@finally {        
    NSLog(@"finally");
}
NSFetchRequest *fetcher = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
// need to define a predicate that will institute weather a message thread is deleted or NOT
[fetcher setEntity:entity];
NSError *error;
NSLog(@"All Records is %@",[contOBJ executeFetchRequest:fetcher error:&error]);
return [contOBJ executeFetchRequest:fetcher error:&error];
```

Comment: How are you getting your managedObjectContext? is it possible that it is nil at any point?

Comment: I'm doing this NSManagedObjectContext *contOBJ =self.managedObjectContext; NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityForNameString  inManagedObjectContext:contOBJ]. then I use the entity here as a fetch to look for specifics on my "MessageLists" entity. and No, my managedObjectContext is not NIL before this line of code is called. the weird thing is, this happens at the start of the app which makes me believe that there's something wrong before the app is terminated (coreData having hanging objects, etc).

Comment: the error always occurs at the same place, the same time (app being opened). I have also tried checking [self.managedObjectModel entities] before the line of code gets execute to determine if "MessageLists" entity is indeed NIL but it's there.

Comment: what is self?  who sets the the managedObjectContext property? when is it set?  Crashes on launch can mean that stuff is not setup yet as you expect it to be.

Comment: since this block of code is in the appdelegate, I refer to Manageobjectcontext as self. but you are giving me a great out-of-the-box idea. will looking it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why my issue was intermittent is not because of my codes but rather changes to iOS 10. Apparently, apple made changes to the way core data is init and declared in the AppDelegate.

> Starting in iOS 10 and macOS 10.12, the NSPersistentContainer handles
>   the creation of the Core Data stack and offers access to the
>   NSManagedObjectContext as well as a number of convenience methods.
>   Prior to iOS 10 and macOS 10.12, the creation of the Core Data stack
>   was more involved.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/InitializingtheCoreDataStack.html

As it turns out, even if I implemented:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [MessageLists fetchRequest];
NSError *error;
NSLog(@"All Records is %@",[context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error]);
```

I would still arrive at the same issue. Besides, I haven't updated my AppDelegate's Core Data codes since iOS 8...

Answer (score 1):

Don't use that old stringly typed stuff, just do this

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [MessageLists fetchRequest];
NSError *error;
NSLog(@"All Records is %@",[context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error]);
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer and wow, it is really simpler than what I though. having said that, it still crashes. I believe I have a good idea why this is happening. the intermittence is now predictable. as what Jon pointed, the issue may stem from my persistentStorage not properly init. or some other core data thing. I will update once re-coding starts!